# Open Source Email Application

Tags: email, open-source

Does anyone here know of an open source email application for Android? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

[K-9 Mail](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fsck.k9&feature=search_result) is open-sourced and is equipped with features like search, push email, multi-folder sync, flagging, filing, signatures, bcc-self and more

[Project Hosted on Google Code](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://k9mail.googlecode.com&usg=AFQjCNFUeJXYqT0BPlWAC6Re63qeFVm88Q)

Answer (score 9):

Android's own Email application is, in fact, [open source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email).